# How to exchange files between Windows 10 guest VM on Linux Arch Host using qemu virtmanger and guestmount while VM is running

Tags: qemu

I am using Garuda, an Arch based Distro with xfce desktop on a Lenovo Thinkpad T480 with i7 8 log. Cores and 32 GB RAM.
I installeda qemu and virt-manager via:

sudo pacman -S qemu virt-manager

sudo systemctl start virtlogd.service

sudo systemctl enable libvirtd.service

sudo virsh net-start default**

sudo pacman -S ebtables dnsmasq

Then I setup the Windows 10 VM using the .iso Image and 4 log. cores and 16000 MB RAM, and after the Installation I used the virtio-win-0.1.229.iso image for the drivers for the virtual devices. Then I installed on the host the libguestfs-tools package with:

sudo pacman -S libguestfs

made a mounting directory for file exchange between Host and Guest with

sudo mkdir /mnt/sda2

mounted the qemu-Win 10-Image with:

sudo guestmount -a /var/lib/libvirt/images/win10.qcow2 -m /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2

and then I could exchange as root, files from the Host via /mnt/sda2 to the C:\ drive of the Windows 10 Guest

but then I mounted the win10.qcow2-Image the VM doesn't start up, "the Image is already in use".

What can I do to have access from Guest to Host-directory or Host to Guest-directory while the VM is running?

Is it a rights-problem?